# making qt calendar arrows larger

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qcalendarwidget

I use the QCalendarWidget to create a calendar.

I made the calendar and its font larger, but I don't know how to make the arrows of the calendar larger too. 
By arrows, I mean to the green ones at the top, that let you go back and forth.

I am working with python 2.7, and using PyQt4.

creating the calendar using the QCalendarWidget -

```
    cal = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(self)
```

IMAGE: You could see that the arrows are not proportional to the calendar's size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to set the iconSize qproperty with Qt Style Sheet:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    cal = QtGui.QCalendarWidget()
    fn = cal.font()
    fn.setPointSize(20)
    cal.setFont(fn)

    cal.setStyleSheet("""
        #qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth{
            qproperty-iconSize: 40px
        }
    """
    )

    cal.resize(640, 480)
    cal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another possible solution is to access each button using findChild and set the iconSize:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    cal = QtGui.QCalendarWidget()
    fn = cal.font()
    fn.setPointSize(20)
    cal.setFont(fn)

    prev_button = cal.findChild(QtGui.QToolButton, "qt_calendar_prevmonth")
    next_button = cal.findChild(QtGui.QToolButton, "qt_calendar_nextmonth")
    for btn in (prev_button, next_button):
        btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))

    cal.resize(640, 480)
    cal.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```